# Ferramenta automatizada para juntar várias folhas de estilos (CSS) em 1 só e para juntar Scripts (JS) em 1 Folha só

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Pesquisei na internet meios de se juntar **Folhas de Estilos** `CSS` e **Folhas de Scripts** `JS` de forma automatizada, porém, não obtive bons resultados.

Possuo cerca de 17 Folhas de Estilo e 15 Scripts, se eu fizer manualmente eu ficarei "doido" e demorarei bastante.

Alguém conhece uma ferramenta online ou software que me possibilite fazer isso de forma automatizada?

> Ex: Mando todos os arquivos (folhas) para o **site** e já baixo o arquivo com as folhas já unidas, ou algum software que faça isso de forma automatizada.

Comment: Da uma olhada no [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)

Comment: @Rodrigo transforme seu comentário em resposta.

Comment: em aplicativos pequenos eu utilizo o ``cat`` e se eu nomear os arquivos com prefixo numérico eu consigo a ordem que quero no arquivo compilado

Comment: @neoprofit que `cat`? Transforme seu comentário em resposta! :D

Comment: @AlexandreLopes fiz conforme sugeriu.Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entre nesse site e faça o upload dos múltiplos arquivos.

http://refresh-sf.com/yui/

Em breve o site será movido, existe um novo endereço sendo informado na página, adicione aos seus favoritos.

Comment: Muito bom! Excelente! Mas o ruim é que estão querendo tirar o site e colocar outro sem muitas funções. Pelo que eu vi o novo site servirá só para minificar as folhas. triste :( Mas vou usá-lo bastante antes que isso aconteça :D

Comment: Ao que parece vai ser apenas visual!

Comment: Tomara que sim! Só que eu vi que não vai ter o yui Compressor

Answer (score 2):

Darei uma resposta simples, que, de forma alguma atende projetos grandes, e resolve compilação e redução de arquivos, mas que eu utilizo em pequenos projetos.

Veja a arvore de exemplo:

```
root
   js/
     - compilado.js
     src/
        - 01-core.js
        - 02-functions.js
        - 03-extra.js
```

Para gerar `compilado.js`:

```
cd js;
cat src/*.js > compilado.js
```

O mesmo pode ser feito com o `css`

Comment: Não entendi. Como faz isso?
Através de um programa? o.O

Comment: ``cat`` e ``cd`` são programas da linha de comando *nix (Linux e Mac) mas que você tbm consegue instalar no Windows, se for o seu caso.

Comment: Obrigado!......

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer "bundling" (juntar vários arquivos CSS e javascript em um) eu uso o a extensão do Web Essentials para o Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web ( http://vswebessentials.com/features/bundling )

Mas pesquisando... encontrei algumas outras que aqui compartilho :

- JAWR - https://jawr.java.net/index.html
- NPM - https://www.npmjs.org/package/bundy
- Flour - http://ricardo.cc/cake-flour/

Essas ferramentas também fazem "minification" ( uma forma de otimizar os arquivos para eles ficarem menores)

Comment: Muito legal! Não conhecia essa extensão do Visual Studio. :D

Answer (score 1):

Há poucos dias estou utilizando uma ferramenta chamada Gulp, que de modo simples você pode criar tarefas para automatizar esse processo de build.
Uma das tarefas mais comuns é concatenar arquivos tanto JS quanto CSS, que é o seu caso.

Dê uma olhada nesses links:
 * Gulp Getting Started - https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#getting-started
 * Gulp Concat - https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat

Se der certo de concatenar os arquivos, talvez também seja uma boa ideia fazer a minificação para que eles diminuam de tamanho, procure por Gulp Uglify e Gulp Minify CSS.

Espero ter te dado novas idéias,
André

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!